# Pass value from EditorFor to method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have `EditorFor` in my View.
Like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().Link, 
   new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email", id= "start" } })
```

Also I Action in controller that find all NULL in table from database and update it with some value, here is code

```
 public ActionResult Update(string start="lol")
 {
     ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

     IEnumerable<InvitationMails> customers = context.InvitationMails
            .Where(c => c.Link == null)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(c => {
                c.Link = start;
                return c;
            });
     foreach (InvitationMails customer in customers)
     {
         // Set that row is changed
         context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
     }
     context.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
 }
```

In Index View I tap button that goes to Update Action and launch it
Here is code

```
<ul class="btn btn-default" style="width: 150px; list-style-type: none; font-size: 16px; margin-left: 20px">
                <li style="color: white">@Html.ActionLink("Добавить почту", "Update", "InvitationMails", null, new { @style = "color:white" })</li>
            </ul>
```

But here is update with static value, and I want to recieve value from VIew. 
How I need to write my code?

Comment: Why do you have a model which is a collection and are trying to bind to something that is not related to your model at all. Its unclear what your trying to achieve. In order to bind to your parameter, your input needs `name="start"`. Since you not binding to anything, just create the input manually

Comment: And then you have shown an action link which appears to be making a GET to your method, but that does not pass the value of your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should basically set `name` attribute of rendered `input`.

If you use MVC 4 you have spacial overload of `EditorFor` for this case.

You can use it like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().Link,
    null,
    "start", //That will set id and name attributes to start
    new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" })
```

Note that you don't need `id="start"` anymore.

**After your update:**

You basically have 2 options.

1s option - use `form`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "InvitationMails", FormMethod.Post)) //maby you need GET
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First().Link,
        null,
        "start", //That will set id and name attributes to start
        new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" })

        <ul class="btn btn-default" style="width: 150px; list-style-type: none; font-size: 16px; margin-left: 20px">
            <li style="color: white">
                <button type="submit" style="color:white">Добавить почту</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
}
```

2nd option - use js on action link click.

Comment: Try your code. Not works. I will now update my question, maybe I don't clearly write it

Comment: @E.S where do you have your `start` value that you want to pass to controller?

Comment: I need to take text from EditorFor and pass it to Update Action result

Comment: @E.S don't you want just use `form` with submit button instead of action link?

Comment: Hm, maybe you're right,so for form how I need to write code?

Do I need to use my method?